# Couldn't start riemann.bin?

Tags: clojure, logstash, riemann

I just untarred the rieman 0.2.5 tarball and ran the

bin/riemann etc/riemann.config

Ruby version: ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux]

Java version "1.6.0_11"

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.3 (Tikanga)

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR [2014-11-21 12:52:43,395] main - riemann.bin - Couldn't start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:5555
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at clojure.core$deref_future.invoke(core.clj:2180)
    at clojure.core$future_call$reify__6320.deref(core.clj:6420)
    at clojure.core$deref.invoke(core.clj:2200)
    at clojure.core$pmap$step__6333$fn__6335.invoke(core.clj:6470)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2855)
    at riemann.core$transition_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:156)
    at clojure.lang.Atom.swap(Atom.java:51)
    at clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:2233)
    at riemann.config$apply_BANG_.invoke(config.clj:268)
    at riemann.bin$_main.doInvoke(bin.clj:63)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at riemann.bin.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:5555
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ConnectionlessBootstrap.bind(ConnectionlessBootstrap.java:204)
    at riemann.transport.udp.UDPServer.start_BANG_(udp.clj:92)
    at riemann.service$fn__8682$G__8676__8684.invoke(service.clj:20)
    at riemann.service$fn__8682$G__8675__8687.invoke(service.clj:20)
    at clojure.core$pmap$fn__6328$fn__6329.invoke(core.clj:6466)
    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4145.invoke(core.clj:1910)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bind(DatagramChannelImpl.java:495)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.bind(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramPipelineSink.bind(NioDatagramPipelineSink.java:129)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioDatagramPipelineSink.java:77)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler.handleDownstream(ExecutionHandler.java:186)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.bind(Channels.java:561)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:189)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ConnectionlessBootstrap.bind(ConnectionlessBootstrap.java:198)
    ... 11 more
WARN [2014-11-21 12:52:43,395] pool-1-thread-1 - riemann.transport.udp - UDP handler caught
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bind(DatagramChannelImpl.java:495)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.bind(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramPipelineSink.bind(NioDatagramPipelineSink.java:129)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioDatagramPipelineSink.java:77)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler.handleDownstream(ExecutionHandler.java:186)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.bind(Channels.java:561)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:189)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ConnectionlessBootstrap.bind(ConnectionlessBootstrap.java:198)
    at riemann.transport.udp.UDPServer.start_BANG_(udp.clj:92)
    at riemann.service$fn__8682$G__8676__8684.invoke(service.clj:20)
    at riemann.service$fn__8682$G__8675__8687.invoke(service.clj:20)
    at clojure.core$pmap$fn__6328$fn__6329.invoke(core.clj:6466)
    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4145.invoke(core.clj:1910)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to state that port 5555 is already in use. Perhaps a previously (aborted) start left a process that still has a handle on the port ?

Do a `netstat -ao` (Windows) or `netstat -ap` (Linux) to see if there's already a listening port 5555, and which process has a handle on it, then kill that process.

Comment: It's java which is opening a port, so I cannot kill that process. Any other workaround?

Comment: Another instance of riemann was running in background thus the conflict. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation with you.

you can open your terminal and enter

> sudo netstat -nap | grep 5555

there will be shown like this:

> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          :::*                    LISTEN      11465/java
>
> udp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          :::*                                2863/java

you can enter this in your terminal

> ps aux | grep 11465

and kill the process.

In most cases, the cause of this error is that you opened two identical services.

You can run this command to check the service status:

> sudo service riemann status

start riemann:

> sudo service riemann start

and end the service is:

sudo service rimann stop